# Importing data using External tables into oracle

Tags: oracle

I am facing an error while importing csv file into oracle using external tables. The error that I faced is
`KUP-04021: field formatting error for field KUP-04037: terminator not found KUP-04101`
and the csv file that I try to import has the line below where it throws error. I found that Oracle considers `â?¡` these symbols as line terminators and hence could not solve it. If any answers, it would e more helpful. Thanks in advance.

"Receive free stateroom upgradesâ?  and free gratuitiesâ?¡. Plus, Grill Suites guests receive complimentary drinksâ? â?"

Comment: You should be able to define your field and line terminators when creating the external table. If your data contains your field terminators (which should never be the case) then you can try to import your entire file into a single column external table and parse it from there.

Comment: the code I used is "CREATE TABLE "SYSTEM"."ECOMP_RATE" 
(..)ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
  (  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
     DEFAULT DIRECTORY DEFAULT_DIR
     ACCESS PARAMETERS 
       (records delimited BY '\r\n'
        fields terminated BY ',' optionally enclosed BY '"' and '"' lrtrim
            missing field VALUES are NULL )
     LOCATION ('comp_rate.csv'))
     REJECT LIMIT unlimited;